# Python code error, code not working properly

Tags: python

After 4th line, even if u type something else other than yes, it still prints okay?

```
x = input("Enter any number of your choice: ")
print("the number you picked is", x)
yes = x
input("       right? : ")

if yes:
    print("ok")
else:
    print("you liar")
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you don't enter anything when you prompt for this:

```
x = input("Enter any number of your choice: ")

if yes: # it's always going to be true
```

Also this is not doing anything:

```
input("       right? : ")
```

you need to assign it to a variable
I think what you want is this:

```
sure = input("       right? : ")

if sure == 'yes':
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use isnumeric() in case you want to check for a number.

Some documentation on isnumeric() is located at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isnumeric.htm

At the moment, you are basically just checking the existence of the variable yes.

BTW: The output for checking up on the number can be rewritten to a formatted statement as follows:

```
print("The number you picked is {:d} right?".format(x))
```

Checking, if the user answers with a "yes", can be done easily as well:

```
yes = input("The number you picked is {:d} right?".format(x))
if (yes == "yes"):
    print("ok")
else:
    print("you liar")
```

In case of python2.x you should use raw_input() instead of input(), which is fine for python3.

Comment: Technically, `if yes` checks if `bool(yes) == True`. For this case, since `yes` is always a string (I"m assuming he's using Python 3.3, so `input` returns a string), this would be `False` if the string is empty, otherwise it would return `True`. If the variable didn't exist (which it has to because it is explicitly defined and not deleted), you would get a `NameError.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check what the user is saying for the "Right?" prompt:

```
x = input("Enter any number of your choice: ")
print("the number you picked is", x)
yes = input("       right? : ") # capture the user input
if yes == "yes": # check if the user said yes
    print("ok")
else:
    print("you liar")
```